# Nested method calls in EJBs attempting to start/create a new transaction in a nested method call

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, ejb

Let's consider two methods `methodA()` annotated with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)` (default) and `methodB()` annotated with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)` in a stateless EJB.

Making a nested call to `methodB()` through `methodA()` does not start/create a new transaction as it appears to be (regardless of what transaction attribute type is used the target method), since the nested call to `methodB()` from `methodA()` uses the `this` pointer/reference (i.e. the actual EJB instance) to invoke `methodB()` which is thus not intercepted by the proxy which is to be injected at run-time by the container and needed to setup the environment before calling a method.

Basic demonstration :

```
@Stateless
public class TestBean implements TestBeanService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    // At a glance, this method should cause an exception but it does not.
    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
    public Long getRowCount() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT count(e) AS cnt FROM Employee e", Long.class).getSingleResult();
    }

    // This method is invoked by the application client.
    // making a nested call to getRowCount() using the "this" pointer.
    @Override
    public void test() {
        Long rowCount = getRowCount();
        System.out.println("rowCount : " + rowCount);
    }
}
```

Although the `getRowCount()` method is decorated with `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)` which should cause an exception at a glance, it successfully returns the number of rows returned by the query.

► This is because the transaction started by the `test()` method is propagated (expanded) to `getRowCount()` i.e. everything happens within the same single transaction.

---

An exception would however, be thrown, if the `getRowCount()` method were to be invoked using a proxy instance obtained through `javax.ejb.SessionContext`. This modification is demonstrated by the following snippet.

```
@Stateless
public class TestBean implements TestBeanService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;

    @Override
    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NEVER)
    public Long getRowCount() {
        return entityManager.createQuery("SELECT count(e) AS cnt FROM Employee e", Long.class).getSingleResult();
    }

    @Override
    public void test() {
        // Invocation to getRowCount() is done by a proxy instance. Hence, it causes an exception,
        // since the transaction started by this method is now not propagated to a subsequent call to getRowCount().
        Long rowCount = sessionContext.getBusinessObject(TestBeanService.class).getRowCount();
        System.out.println("rowCount : " + rowCount);
    }
}
```

Since the `getRowCount()` method uses `TransactionAttributeType.NEVER`, the above method call to `getRowCount()` causes the following exception to be thrown contradicting to the first case.

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: EJB cannot be invoked in global transaction
```

► This is because the transaction started by the `test()` method is now **not** propagated (expanded) to `getRowCount()` as happens in the first case because this method is now invoked through a proxy instance (thus, not directly through the `this` pointer as usual - the actual EJB instance).

Obtaining a proxy instance through `javax.ejb.SessionContext` and invoking a method on that proxy instance is a kind of hack. I do not think it is supposed to be used in real applications.

Is there any other way to start/create a new transaction in a nested method call whenever needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transaction attributes are honored only when you access the bean via interface/proxy, not as internal method, as you observed. So in addition to access it via `SessionContext` you could also have a reference: `@EJB TestBeanService serviceBean` in your class and access it via `serviceBean.getRowCount()` (also kind of a hack).

Comment: A self injection through the CDI `@Inject` annotation ends with an exception, `org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001443: Pseudo scoped bean has circular dependencies.`. Perhaps, it is [a missing feature or a bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-414) in the current CDI implementation. `@EJB` has to be used as a work around in such cases.